# How to mutate a data.table for a lots of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have a data.table that includes column from P01 to PP20, and S01 to S20. Now I'd like to add 20 more columns through mutate function:

```
library(dplyr)

production50m <- mutate(production50m, S01_P01 = S01 / P01)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S02_P02 = S02 / P02)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S03_P03 = S03 / P03)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S04_P04 = S04 / P04)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S05_P05 = S05 / P05)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S06_P06 = S06 / P06)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S07_P07 = S07 / P07)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S08_P08 = S08 / P08)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S09_P09 = S09 / P09)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S10_P10 = S10 / P10)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S11_P11 = S11 / P11)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S12_P12 = S12 / P12)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S13_P13 = S13 / P13)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S14_P14 = S14 / P14)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S15_P15 = S15 / P15)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S16_P16 = S16 / P16)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S17_P17 = S17 / P17)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S18_P18 = S18 / P18)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S19_P19 = S19 / P19)
production50m <- mutate(production50m, S20_P20 = S20 / P20)
```

Apparently it's not a smart move write 20 lines of code. Is there any ways to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using a loop?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? You can use `mutate_at` or `mutate_all` from `dplyr`, and I have a feeling this might be a problem you could solve by reshaping the data

Comment: DT[,(paste0(“S”,1:20,”_P”,1:20)) := lapply(1:20, function(n) get(paste0(“S”,n)) / get(paste0(“P”,n)))]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using base R, which can avoid typing the `mutate` command so many times. Assuming your data frame is called `dat` with 40 columns as 20 of them with the beginning of `S` and the other `20` as `P`. `dat2` is the final output.

```
# Select the columns from S01 to S20
dat_S <- dat[, sprintf("S%02d", 1:20)]

# Select the columns from P01 to P20
dat_P <- dat[, sprintf("P%02d", 1:20)]

# Calculate the new columns
dat_SP <- dat_S/dat_P

# Rename the columns
names(dat_SP) <- paste(sprintf("S%02d", 1:20), sprintf("P%02d", 1:20), sep = "_")

# Combine dat_SP to the original data frame
dat2 <- cbind(dat, dat_SP)
```

If you are really working on a `data.table`, we can still use the same strategy. Please notice that the way we select the column by names is different than the regular data frame.

```
library(data.table)

# Convert to data.table
setDT(dat)

# Select the columns from S01 to S20
S_cols <- sprintf("S%02d", 1:20)
dat_S <- dat[, ..S_cols]

# Select the columns from P01 to P20
P_cols <- sprintf("P%02d", 1:20)
dat_P <- dat[, ..P_cols]

# Calculate the new columns
dat_SP <- dat_S/dat_P

# Rename the columns
names(dat_SP) <- paste(sprintf("S%02d", 1:20), sprintf("P%02d", 1:20), sep = "_")

# Combine dat_SP to the original data frame
dat2 <- cbind(dat, dat_SP)
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(4749)

dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(120), ncol = 40))
names(dat) <- c(sprintf("S%02d", 1:20), sprintf("P%02d", 1:20))
```

Comment: Wow! That's really what I want. Thank you so so much!

Comment: Can I ask one more question here?

Comment: Let's say all P, S and SP columns has 100 obs. How can do a loop if where P01 is less than 5, then set P01 to zero, and set S01 and S01_P01 to zero at the same place. Same as P02, P03,......P20.

Comment: @shyzhan Please ask a new question with reproducible example. It is difficult to answer this kind of updates.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using a mixture of `dplyr`, `purrr` and `rlang`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
# list of the variables you want to combine
library(stringr) # for str_pad function
var_names <- map(c("S", "P"), ~ paste0(., str_pad(1:20, 2, side = 'left', pad = '0')))

# create fake df since no data provided
df <- unlist(var_names) %>% 
  map_dfc(.f = function(x) {
    data_frame(!!x := rnorm(100, 40, 2))
  })

# solution - there are places this could be fancier, but this gets the job done
df2 <- map2_dfc(var_names[[1]], var_names[[2]], .f = function(x, y) {
  var_name = paste(x, y, sep = "_")
  data_frame(!!var_name := df[[x]]/ df[[y]])
}) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can point to the *n*th column like this:

```
myTable[,n]
```

where *n* is the number of the column.  Use a loop to iterate through the columns you want to work on.  For example:

```
for(n in 1:ncol(myTable){
myTable[,n] <- #put what you want the column to be here
}
```

You cannot add new columns to the table this way.  Instead, you can add blank columns to your table first:

```
myTable$name_of_new_column <- NA
```